Как вывести поток с камеры подключенной к облаку?
У меня есть камеры которые подключаются к приложению icsee (из инструкции).
Я смог подключиться к ним через приложение на пк (polyvision cms 28.12.2020)
Через облако по серийному номеру камеры и логину + паролю соответственно.
протокол XM (NETIP) P.S. так написанно в polyvision cms.
Я хочу продвинуться дальше и вывести видео поток на свой сайт.
Используя node js или php не важно. Вопрос в том куда копать, я не могу найти ни нужной блиблиотеки чтобы получить видео поток

Нашел какую-то китайскую документацию источник(https://forum.devline.ru/topic/5306-%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-xmeye/)
они видимо переехали на https://aops.jftech.com/#/
Тут есть какая-то документация мб она поможет

Для вставки на сайт потока с вашей камеры, вставьте такой код:


<video src="rtsp://111.222.333.444:34567/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?" controls></video>



где 111.222.333.444 следует заменить реальным ip-адресом Вашей камеры, а чуть правее отредактировать реальный логин и пароль для входа в программу polyvision cms. Взято от сюда: Удалённая работа с видеорегистраторами через ПО CMS
Правда, там ссылка приводится для примера её вставки в VLC media player, но и для сайта она подойдёт.

А если ip не белый? Как вообще polyvision подключается к камере через облако? Если у них есть только серийник, как я мог бы организовать такое же подключение на nose Js к примеру?
